# dynamic content adding in admin panel in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin, all backend is finished and I want it to add quite big sets of data, so I want to add more fields dynamically like this:

[image: wordpress]

I got some simple adding form, but it takes long time to add and is counterintuitive for an end user. Is there some wordpress function that can do this? Or even a direction someone can point me to (or plugin examples).

Comment: You can add dom elements easily using jQuery also

Comment: this I know, but since I'm not familiar with it, I counted on a fact, that maybe it is managed by some wordpress hooks or something.